# Getting: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified. Error

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

Java is telling me that they cannot find the resource to load the fxml file, but I am not sure why considering the file is literally in the same directory. I know this error may also throw if something is wrong with the fxml file; but I dont know how to troubleshoot if that is the case. Can someone please offer guidance?

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="714.0" prefWidth="699.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="hotelmanagementsystemapp.ReservationSystemUIController">
   <children>
      <HBox maxHeight="100.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="400.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Button ellipsisString="~" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="560.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="71.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#286487 0%, #5886A1 100%);" text="Home" textFill="WHITE" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Avenir Book" size="19.0" />
               </font>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button ellipsisString="~" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="560.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="71.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#286487 0%, #5886A1 100%);" text="Reservation System" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Avenir Book" size="19.0" />
               </font>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button ellipsisString="~" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="560.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="71.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#286487 0%, #5886A1 100%);" text="Home" textFill="WHITE" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Avenir Book" size="19.0" />
               </font>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button ellipsisString="~" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="560.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="71.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#286487 0%, #5886A1 100%);" text="Home" textFill="WHITE" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Avenir Book" size="19.0" />
               </font>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button ellipsisString="~" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="560.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="71.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#286487 0%, #5886A1 100%);" text="Home" textFill="WHITE" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Avenir Book" size="19.0" />
               </font>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button ellipsisString="~" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="560.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="71.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#286487 0%, #5886A1 100%);" text="Home" textFill="WHITE" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Avenir Book" size="19.0" />
               </font>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.381635581061693, 0.8694404591104734" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="699.0">
         <items>
            <VBox maxWidth="300.0" prefHeight="159.0" prefWidth="234.0" spacing="5.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Booking Information:" />
                  <Separator prefWidth="200.0" />
                  <HBox prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="144.0" style="-fx-border-color: #979797;">
                     <children>
                        <Label minHeight="33.0" minWidth="52.0" text="* From" />
                        <DatePicker maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="27.0" minWidth="144.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="144.0" style="-fx-border-color: #979797;">
                     <children>
                        <Label minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="* To" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <DatePicker maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="27.0" minWidth="144.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="5.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </DatePicker>
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="144.0" style="-fx-border-color: #979797;">
                     <children>
                        <Label minHeight="30.0" minWidth="79.0" text="Room Type" />
                        <ComboBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="27.0" minWidth="115.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="5.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                        </ComboBox>
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </HBox>
                  <AnchorPane maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <children>
                        <HBox minWidth="55.0" style="-fx-border-color: #979797;">
                           <children>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" minHeight="42.0" minWidth="39.0" text="No." textAlignment="CENTER" />
                              <ComboBox maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="27.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="60.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets top="8.0" />
                                 </HBox.margin>
                              </ComboBox>
                           </children>
                           <padding>
                              <Insets right="8.0" />
                           </padding>
                        </HBox>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                  <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button layoutX="174.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #01B0EA;" text="SEARCH" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="7.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
            <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
               <children>
                  <BorderPane maxHeight="300.0" maxWidth="400.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="197.0" prefWidth="255.0" HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES">
                     <top>
                        <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="190.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                           <children>
                              <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="April" HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </children>
                        </HBox>
                     </top>
                     <center>
                        <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                           <children>
                              <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="190.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="1" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="2" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="3" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="4" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="5" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="6" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="7" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="190.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="8" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="9" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="10" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="11" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="12" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="13" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="14" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="190.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="15" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="16" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                       <opaqueInsets>
                                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                       </opaqueInsets>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="17" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="18" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="19" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="20" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="key.unspecifiedkey" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="21" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="190.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="22" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="23" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="24" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="25" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="26" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="27" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="28" />
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="190.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="29" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="30" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                    <Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="31" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <WebView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
         </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
         <children>
            <Separator prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="14.0">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets right="5.0" top="17.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Separator>
            <Label minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="83.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3D91C1;" text="Available" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="17.0" />
               </font>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
            </Label>
            <Separator prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="538.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="17.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Separator>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
      <TableView maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="282.0" prefWidth="699.0" stylesheets="@reservationsystemui.css" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn maxWidth="775.0" minWidth="109.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Room No." />
          <TableColumn maxWidth="1065.0" minWidth="149.0" prefWidth="149.0" text="Duration" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="1140.0" minWidth="160.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Notes" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="929.0" minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Add. Packages" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="1070.0" minWidth="150.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Action" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Directory Structure:

[image]

Start function:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException 
    {

       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ReservationSystemUI.fxml")); //<— ERROR            


        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.setMinWidth(scene.widthProperty().doubleValue());
        stage.setMinHeight(scene.heightProperty().doubleValue());
        stage.show();
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
Executing /Users/norriswise/NetBeansProjects/HotelManagementSystemApp/dist/run1290999908/HotelManagementSystemApp.jar using platform /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
Feb 12, 2018 9:52:26 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified. //<— ERROR
file:/Users/norriswise/NetBeansProjects/HotelManagementSystemApp/dist/run1290999908/HotelManagementSystemApp.jar!/hotelmanagementsystemapp/ReservationSystemUI.fxml:182

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.resolvePrefixedValue(FXMLLoader.java:421)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:363)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:325)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:235)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at hotelmanagementsystemapp.HotelManagementSystemApp.start(HotelManagementSystemApp.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application hotelmanagementsystemapp.HotelManagementSystemApp
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory /Users/norriswise/NetBeansProjects/HotelManagementSystemApp/dist/run1290999908
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Post the FXML file. Are you [accessing resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#resource_resolution) in it?

Comment: I have posted the FXML. I don't believe so. I haven't imported anything.

Comment: What do imports have to do with anything? Which line is line 182?

Comment: 182 >> `<Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="15" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />`

Comment: @James_D The import statements are importing javafx components. This code was generated using Scene Builder; but this would be here regardless.

Comment: I figured it out, the `ellipsisString` attribute needs you to specify a key to replace the string in the button with if the box gets too small. `%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified` is invalid and will look for an outside resource (when none is given)

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the hint on line 182; I dont know why I didnt just look at that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this answer because I figured it out on my own. 
Thanks for the hint @James_D.

For buttons the ellipsisString attribute needs you to specify a key to replace the string in the button if the box gets too small. `%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified` is invalid and will look for an outside resource (when none is given), and will crash the program.

```
<Button ellipsisString="%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="15" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
```

`%key.unspecifiedkey.unspecified` Needs to be replaced with whatever symbol you are using. I am using `~`:

```
<Button ellipsisString="~" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="19.0" text="15" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
```